# Python Sorting List according to pattern

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I have lists which I need to sort according to Patterns. The following Dictionary is the pattern. Each Key of the dictionary has the values that can follow it in the list.

```
pattern = {'West'   : ['North','Central'],
           'North'  : ['West','Alpha','Bravo','Central'],
           'Alpha'  : ['Bravo','North'],
           'Bravo'  : ['North','Alpha','Central','Middle'],
           'Central': ['West','North','Bravo','Middle'],
           'Middle' : ['Bravo','Central','South'],
           'South'  : ['Middle'] 
          }
```

Let's say the list that require sorting is:

```
listA = ['West','North','Middle','Bravo']
```

Looking at the list we see that it started with 'West'. Looking the pattern dictionary, `'West'` can be followed by 'North' or 'Central'. So in our list we have `'North'` So the next Item will be 'North' `['West','North']`

`'North'` can be followed by 'West','Alpha','Bravo' or 'Central'. Looking at our items in the list we have `'Bravo'`
`['West','North','Bravo']`.

`'Bravo'` can be followed by 'North','Alpha','Central' or 'Middle'. Looking at our items in the list we have `'Middle'`

so The sorted list shall be:

```
resultA = ['West','North','Bravo','Middle']
```

Another Example:

```
listB = ['South','Central','West','Middle']
```

The Sorted list Shall be:

```
resultB = ['South','Middle','Central','West']
```

In all cases the first Element of the list is correct and shall be followed according to the pattern.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your logic...

Comment: The list items describe geographical locations, and I need to identify the path moved. Let us say the object started the movement from 'Central'. Looking at the pattern, the next location can be either 'West', 'North', 'Bravo' or 'Middle'. And so on for each location. Now the thing is I already have these locations but some of them were missing some locations and I added them to the end of the list. I have to sort so that the actual path is correct. I hope this is clear now

Comment: I added more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def sort_paths(listA):
    new_list = []
    # listA = ['West','North','Middle','Bravo']

    def walk(name):
        if name not in new_list: # checking if its point hasn't been walked through
            new_list.append(name)
            if pattern.get(name): # if there's ways to go
                for way in pattern[name]: # for every way
                    if way in listA: # if its needed to be walked through
                        walk(way)

    for name in listA: # Trying to walk from all starting points.
        walk(name)

    return new_list
# ['West', 'North', 'Bravo', 'Middle']
```

It's a recursion function, that adds "name" to a new_list and calls itself to points it can follow from "name" according to "pattern".
Make sure you assign pattern before using this code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think it works. Just few question here: 1- currently we are using a global new list and this would require me to create a global new list each time. How to overcome this?

Comment: 2- If using on thousands of lists, how to improve the speed of this?

Comment: 1- Comment out listA assigning, replace "print(new_list)" with "return new_list", wrap all code in a function. I changed code, now it's a function.

Comment: 2- Idk, maybe writing code in c++, or at least using cython module. I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be like a 3 dimensional path, as you described you can go from say     'Middle' to Bravo Central or South, but there is no pattern like from the bottom of the dict you can go one geo location and from the 1 before the last you can go to 3.
{2,4,2,4,4,3,1}, i'd suggest to draw this and add a function that would distinguish the path to sort this.
loop over the dict keys and check if its in the list(as West is a key and a value in the whole dict) once you find the start point from there go over the contents of the key (the values) and see which one is == to list[1] (as list[0] has been used) using this logic add the value to the new empty list to sort it.

Comment: I did not understand this method. Can you detail it please?

Comment: like:
listA=['West','North','Bravo','Middle']
emptylist=[]
i=0
for key in dict:
    if dict[key] == list[i]:
        emptylist += list[i]

for key in dict:
    if dict[list[i]] == list[i+1] #if the value for the first key we check is in the next
        emptylist += list[i+1]
        i+=1
following this the key (list[i]) will compare values associated to it with the next item on the list as it iterates over whatever is in the dict